# Decompose and process time series in binary matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, time-series, asymptotic-complexity

How can I decompose a time series to distribute each row of the matrix formed with less complexity than O (n ^ 2)?

For example. I have a time series of 3 seconds containing the values: 2,1,4. I need to decompose it to take a 4x3 matrix, where 3 is the number of elements of time series and 4 the maximum value. With this we build the binary matrix que would:

1 1 1

1 0 1

0 0 1

0 0 1

Each row is sent without information from the other or the original series to a distributed element in the network.

Comment: It is really unclear how the matrix is constructed and what should be the decomposed result.

Comment: So what's the problem? Find the maximum value (`O(n)`). Then for each entry, create the column (`O(n * max)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity is `n*M`, where `M` is the max value.

If you want to go below that complexity you must use a better encoding. For instance, use [run length encoding](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) to encode the `0`s in the rows.